# How can i run this command X times (!command [X times])? discord bot, discord.js

Tags: discord.js

So I have a command for my discord music bot, here's the command:

```
    run: async function (client, message, args) {
    
        let channel = message.member.voice.channel;
        if (!channel) return sendError("I'm sorry but you need to be in a voice channel to play music!", message.channel);

    const lofiSongs = ["listen before i go billie","Billie Eilish ~ No Time To Die  Slowed to Perfection","Billie Eilish - Six Feet Under ","Chelsea Cutler - Crazier Things","All Kids Are Depressed (Slowed to Perfection)","Close To You- The Carpenters (ukulele cover) | Reneé Dominique","the hills || slowed","Powfu - Death Bed (Slowed To Perfection)","maroon 5 - memories (slowed + reverb)","Ashe - Moral Of The Story (Slowed + Lyrics)","Olivia Rodrigo - traitor (Lyrics)","kina - can we kiss forever [slowed + reverb]","Claire Rosinkranz - Backyard Boy (Lyrics)","comethru - jeremy zucker cover by kimswizzled","[DOXTAPE] Maddox(마독스) - At My Worst (Pink Sweat$ Cover)","Be Alright by Dean Lewis | acoustic cover by Jada Facer","The One That Got Away by Katy Perry | cover by Jada Facer","Let Her Go - Passenger (Official Video Cover by Jasmine Thompson)","Can't Help Falling In Love | Elvis Presley (cover)","IT'S YOU - ALI GATIE［ｓｌｏｗｅｄ ＋ ｒｅｖｅｒｂ］starmilk","All Kids Are Depressed (Slowed to Perfection)","billie eilish khalid - lovely","Duncan Laurence - Arcade","yellow","Heartbreak Anniversary","dancing with your ghout","heater tate macrae","hold on","watch billie eilish","martin and gina slowed reverb","Kali Uchis - telepatía (Cover by Lesha)","leaving on a jet plane macarone project","fly me to the moon yungrythm","close to you renee dominnique","blue moon jaritenph remix","run away","let me down slowely","little do you know","gnash feat. Olivia o'brien - I hate u, I love u (Consoul Trainin Remix)","ocaen eyes","hostage","remendy of broken heart","jocelyn floers","CKay - Love Nwantiti (Acoustic Version)","Tate McRae - friends don’t look at friends that way"]



    const randomLofi = lofiSongs[Math.floor(Math.random() * lofiSongs.length)];

    var searched = await yts.search(randomLofi) 
 
    const msg = message

        const url = "";
        var serverQueue = message.client.queue.get(message.guild.id);

        let songInfo = null;
        let song = null;
        if (url.match(/^(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?(m\.)?(youtube\.com|youtu\.?be)\/.+$/gi)) {
            try {
                songInfo = await ytdl.getInfo(url);
                if (!songInfo) return sendError("Looks like i was unable to find the song on YouTube", message.channel);
                song = {
                    id: songInfo.videoDetails.videoId,
                    title: songInfo.videoDetails.title,
                    url: songInfo.videoDetails.video_url,
                    img: songInfo.player_response.videoDetails.thumbnail.thumbnails[0].url,
                    duration: songInfo.videoDetails.lengthSeconds,
                    ago: songInfo.videoDetails.publishDate,
                    views: String(songInfo.videoDetails.viewCount).padStart(10, " "),
                    req: message.author,
                };
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
                return message.reply(error.message).catch(console.error);
            }
        } else {
            try {

                songInfo = searched.videos[0];
                song = {
                    id: songInfo.videoId,
                    title: Util.escapeMarkdown(songInfo.title),
                    views: String(songInfo.views).padStart(10, " "),
                    url: songInfo.url,
                    ago: songInfo.ago,
                    img: songInfo.image,
                    req: message.author,
                };
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
                return message.reply(error.message).catch(console.error);
            }
        }

        if (serverQueue) {
            serverQueue.songs.push(song);
            let thing = new MessageEmbed()
                .setAuthor("Song has been added to queue")
                .setThumbnail(song.img)
                .setColor("#fffdd0")
                .addField("Name", song.title, true)
                .addField("Duration", song.duration, true)
                .addField("Playlist", "Lofi")
                .setFooter(`Views: ${song.views} | ${song.ago}`);
            return message.channel.send(thing);
        }

        const queueConstruct = {
            textChannel: message.channel,
            voiceChannel: channel,
            connection: null,
            songs: [],
            volume: 80,
            playing: true,
            loop: true,
        };
        message.client.queue.set(message.guild.id, queueConstruct);
        queueConstruct.songs.push(song);

        const play = async (song) => {

            const queue = message.client.queue.get(message.guild.id);
            if (!song) {  
                message.client.queue.delete(message.guild.id);
                return;
            }
            
            
            let stream = null;
            if (song.url.includes("youtube.com")) {
                stream = await ytdl(song.url);
                stream.on("error", function (er) {
                    if (er) {
                        if (queue) {
                            queue.songs.shift();
                            play(queue.songs[0]);
                            return sendError(`An unexpected error has occurred.\nPossible type \`${er}\``, message.channel);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            queue.connection.on("disconnect", () => message.client.queue.delete(message.guild.id));

            const dispatcher = queue.connection.play(ytdl(song.url, { quality: "highestaudio", highWaterMark: 1 << 25, type: "opus" })).on("finish", () => {
                const shiffed = queue.songs.shift();
                if (queue.loop === false) {
                    queue.songs.push(shiffed);
                }
                play(queue.songs[0]);
            });

            dispatcher.setVolumeLogarithmic(queue.volume / 100);
            let thing = new MessageEmbed()
                .setAuthor("PussyMusic Has Started Playing Music")
                .setImage(song.img)
                .setColor("#fffdd0")
                .addField("Name", song.title, true)
                .addField("Views", song.views, true)
                .addField("Requested by", song.req.tag, true)
                .setFooter(`PussyMusic`);
            queue.textChannel.send(thing);
            
        };

        try {
            const connection = await channel.join();
            queueConstruct.connection = connection;
            play(queueConstruct.songs[0]);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(`I could not join the voice channel: ${error}`);
            message.client.queue.delete(message.guild.id);
            await channel.leave();
            return sendError(`I could not join the voice channel: ${error}`, message.channel);

const executeTimes = 5;

for (let i = 0; i < executeTimes; i++) {
   <Command>.execute(...);
}

            }
        }
    };
```

Im pretty new to coding, sorry for my bad knowledge.
As I said I want the command to run X times, Example:
!Command 4 (will run the command 4 times, It means the bot should play 4 songs)
I realy struggle with this code, so thanks if you're  helping :)

Comment: Here, I changed the code, sry.

Comment: Can you edit your question to conform to our guidance on [ask] and creating a [mre]? As of right now it's extremely unclear where you're getting stuck in this implementation; all you've explained is what you're trying to do.

Comment: What's wrong with your current code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way (and maybe buggy way) is to just create `for loop` for it.

**Personal note:** I would add cap to the times people can use the command, to avoid spam and possible rate limit issues.

For loop basically can be as simple as:

```js
if(!isNaN(args[0]){
      for (let i = 0; i < args[0]; i++){
            //Run rest of your code here
      }
}
```

There is not much to go on with your current questions code, so this is the simplest way I can imagine explaining this. Create `for loop` for it *and cap it to prevent spam*

Comment: The OP already tried a `for` loop it seems. Check the bottom of the code